# python -m pip install --upgrade pip does not work

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, version, upgrade

Upgrading pip does not do anything, just tells me to upgrade Pip again and that the requirements are satisfied--however, I am on an old pip version. This is Python27, I get the same issue whether I am in a virtual environment or not.

**Output:**

```
C:\Python27>python -m pip install --upgrade pip

Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\python27\lib\site-packages

You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 19.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

**Versions Installed:**

```
    $ pip --version
    pip 9.0.1 from c:\python27\lib\site-packages (python 2.7)

    $ pip --version
    pip 9.0.1 from c:\users\aroytikh\dev\flask-tutorial\venv\lib\site- 
    packages (python 2.7)
    (venv)
```

Comment: for a fuller discussion on this issue see this: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9912

Comment: For pip 21.2.4, install using the `user` flag

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it [how to update pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52992486/how-to-update-python-pip) will help you and make sure that you are running command prompt as **Administrator**. you can do this by right click on the "**Command Prompt**" application and choose "**Run as administrator**" and type this command in your command prompt.

```
    python -m pip install -U pip
```

try this if it isn't working for you..

- Download [Pip 19.1.1](https://pypi.org/project/pip/#files)
- Install Pip using this command

```
    $ python -m pip install downloads/pip-19.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

or if it is tar.gz file then

```
    $ python -m pip install downloads/pip-19.1.1.tar.gz
```

Comment: thank you so much! this worked!! Will I be able to update my virutal environment in the same way?

Comment: for people that need a command to download it: `wget https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cb/28/91f26bd088ce8e22169032100d4260614fc3da435025ff389ef1d396a433/pip-20.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl -O ~/pip20.2.4` then do `python -m pip install ~/pip20.2.4
` but make sure you download the most recent version though.