# Install Python package inside a Jupyter Notebook kernel

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, python-venv, jupyter-kernel

Inside a Jupyter Notebook I have managed to install a Python kernel with

```
!python -m ipykernel install --user --name other-env --display-name "Python (other-env)"
```

as informed [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html) and it is available with other kernels on the menu **Kernel** → **Change kernel** and

```
!jupyter kernelspec list
```

will also show them

```
Available kernels:
  avenv         C:\Users\Full Name\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\avenv
  chatterbot    C:\Users\Full Name\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\chatterbot
  othervenv     C:\Users\Full Name\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\othervenv
  python3       C:\Users\Full Name\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\share\jupyter\kernels\python3
```

Then I try to install Python a package using

```
%pip install a_package
```

as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56190436/9475509) that said

> with % (instead of !) it will install `a_package` into the current kernel (rather than into the instance of Python that launched the notebook).

But what I have got that it installs `a_package` to all kernels, or `%pip list` will list the same installed packages in all kernels.

Is there a way to install Python package only to an active Jupyter Notebook kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short answer

Path of python executable in JSON file of Jupyter kernel should point to python executable in related virtual environment.

## Long answer

After some tries the steps can be summarized as follow.

### Python virtual environment

1. Create Python virtual environment from a shell, e.g. PowerShell, as in [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html), in a folder (in this case it is `c:\venvs\butiran`)

```
PS C:\> python -m venv c:\venvs\butiran
```

2. Change directory to the folder, e.g in this case is `butiran` in `venvs` (folder for all virtual environments)

```
PS C:\> cd venvs\butiran
PS C:\venvs\butiran>
```

3. Activate virtual environment as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55745233/9475509)

```
PS C:\venvs\butiran> Scripts\activate
(butiran) PS C:\venvs\butiran>
```

4. Update `pip` as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52992541/9475509)

```
(butiran) PS C:\venvs\butiran> python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

5. Install `ipykernel` as in [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html#kernels-for-different-environments)

```
(butiran) PS C:\venvs\butiran> pip install ipykernel
```

6. Deactivate virtual enviroment in powershell as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69650628/9475509)

```
(butiran) PS C:\venvs\butiran> deactivate
PS C:\venvs\butiran>
```

### Jupyter kernel

1. Install `ipykernel` for Jupyter Notebook as in [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html#kernels-for-different-environments)

```
PS C:\venvs\butiran> python -m ipykernel install --user --name butiran --display-name "Python (butiran)"
Installed kernelspec butiran in C:\Users\Full Name\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\butiran
PS C:\venvs\butiran>
```

2. Show JSON file of installed kernel

```
PS C:\venvs\butiran> cat "C:\Users\Full Name\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\butiran\kernel.json"
{
 "argv": [
  "C:\\Users\\Full Name\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\python.exe",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "Python (butiran)",
 "language": "python",
 "metadata": {
  "debugger": true
 }
}
PS C:\venvs\butiran>
```

3. Change path to `python.exe`

- from `C:\\Users\\Full Name\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\python.exe`
- to `C:\\venvs\\butiran\\Scripts\\python.exe`

### Jupyter Notebook

1. Lanuch Jupyter Notebook from PowerShell

```
PS C:\> jupyter notebook
```

2. Open existing notebook or create a new one.
3. Change kernel from menu **Kernel** → **Change kernel** → **Python (butiran)**.
4. Install `a_package` using only in active kernel

```
%pip install a_package
```

or with

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install a_package
```

5. Show the package globally

```
!pip show a_package
```

will give

```
WARNING: Package(s) not found: a_package
```

while show the package in active kernel

```
%pip show a_package
```

will give

```
Name: a_package
Version: ..
Summary: ..
..
Location: c:\venvs\butiran\lib\site-packages
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I have used to overcome this issue

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install a_package
```

Comment: Will that install the `a_package` globally or only in active Jupyter kernel, @user13374981?

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu, you can try this file path and files:

conda environment name:  rag

```
vi ~/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/rag/kernel.json

which python

/home/user/miniconda3/envs/rag/bin/python

change the python binary path to the one from which python in the active conda environment


vi ~/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/rag/kernel.json


{
 "argv": [
  "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/rag/bin/python",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "rag",
 "language": "python",
 "metadata": {
  "debugger": true
 }
}
~
```